# Table-per-Hierarchy inheritance in Entity Framework 7

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, inheritance, entity-framework-core

I'm using Entity Framework beta 8 and Code First to work with SQLite Database.

I need to have TPH inheritance, but by default it uses TPT inheritance.

Here is a part of my code:

```
 public abstract partial class Amenity
 {
    [Key]
    public int AmenityId { get; set; }
    public string AmenityName { get; set; }
 }

 public class AmenityCountable : Amenity
 {
    public int AmenityMinValue { get; set; }
    public int AmenityMaxValue { get; set; }
    public string AmenityTypeName { get; set; }
 }

 public class AmenityOptionable : Amenity
 {
    public bool CanHaveMultipleValues { get; set; }
 }

 public class KMContext : DbContext
 {
    public virtual DbSet<Amenity> Amenities { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AmenityCountable> AmenityCountable { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AmenityOptionable> AmenityOptionable { get; set; }
 }
```

How do I modify it so that it uses TPH inheritance?

Comment: Got no experience with EF7, but in EF6 we are using ToTable for the TPH mapping. Try to mark classes AmenityCountable  and AmenityOptionable  with [Table("Amenity")] attribute.

Comment: @3615 I tried so, but when use Add-Migration I get following error: "Cannot use table 'Amenity' in schema '' for entity 'AmenityCountable' since it is being used for another entity."

Answer (score 0):

TPH will be available in the RC release

see [github entityframework](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3495) about TPH